# how to restrict the 2 same jars are loaded with diffrent versions

Tags: java, apache, maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using Apache Maven to building the project..

Problem is some jars are added two times with the different versions.

httpclient-4.0.3
httpclient-4.3.3

httpcore-4.0.1
httpcore-4.3.2

jackson-core-asl-1.6.7
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13

i want the higher version of jars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually what you would do is look first at the dependency tree and see where the same jars are coming from:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

After you tracked down where the different dependencies come from you, as in your case, you pick the ones that are older and you go ahead and add a `<exclusion/>` tag inside the dependency that retrieves the older ones. 
Example of how to exclude a dependency inside another dependency:
Let us presume you have `hibernate` and `ehcache` dependencies in your `pom.xml`. If `hibernate` `3.2.6.ga`, for example, has inside `ehcache`, but it is an older version and we don't want that version. So in order to exclude `ehcache` from `hibernate` dependency we would do the following

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
     <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
             <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Now, I would help you and add the correct exclusions to the dependencies that are retrieving your older dependencies, but since I am not able to see your `pom.xml` it is hard to help more.